# Unintended Iteration of a specific line inside a For Loop

Tags: c++

Do not worry about the purpose of the code. But I will post it below for reference:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numberOfStudents;

    cout << "Please enter the number of students in the class:\n ";
    cin >> numberOfStudents;

    string temporaryname,
           realname;

    for (int count = 0; count < numberOfStudents; count++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the name of the student";
        getline(cin, temporaryname);

        if (temporaryname == temporaryname);

        else if (temporaryname < realname)
        {
            realname = temporaryname;
        }
    }
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Now the output shows this:

```
Please enter the number of students in the class:
 5
Please enter the name of the student
Please enter the name of the student
```

See the repeated "Please enter the name of the student"? Why is it doing that? I haven't got the slightest clue why is it repeating the same line. Also take note that I am a beginner C++ programmer. Please keep your explanations simple.

Comment: Read your code out-loud, including the loops. This will show you your error.

Comment: I will keep that programming practice tip in the future. Thanks. But I still don't see it though.

Comment: Implementation issues belong on StackOverflow.  If you happen to be question banned on StackOverflow, please ***do not*** ask implementation questions here in an attempt to get around the ban.  Doing so will merely add to the sites where you're not allowed to ask anymore.

Comment: Thanks for that information. But I wasn't banned in StackOverflow. I did not know that Implementation issues is specifically for that website and not in Stackexchange. I apologize for that.

Comment: What is the purpose of the line `if (temporaryname == temporaryname);`

Comment: See [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). This is a very small program; you *should* be able to spot what's wrong unless you just plain don't understand how branches, loops, and `cout`/`cin` work. If you still don't see it, then go slower. P.S. We're not saying this to be mean to you. You need to figure out how to debug while your programs are still small, or you'll be hopelessly lost when they get big.

Comment: @FredOverflow I was ranking names of students that was entered by the user. And at the end of the program I will post who has the name that is **alphabetically** first and  **alphabetically** last.                                        if(temporaryname == temporaryname) was made to start the iteration.

Comment: @Doval I find your comment to be professional and informative. I do not mind being corrected. Thanks for the website, I will add it to my bookmark list.

Comment: An if statement with a condition that is always true will not start any iterations.

Comment: `if (temporaryname == temporaryname);` is a no-op, unless side-effects are involved (which is probably a really bad idea).  It does have the unhappy effect of commenting out your `else` statement.

Answer (score 2):

After this statement

```
cin >> numberOfStudents;
```

the new line character is still in the input buffer.

The next read function

```
getline(cin, temporaryname);
```

reads the buffer until it encounters this new line character.

You should use member function `ignore` before the loop that to ignore all characters in the buffer before using getline.
For example

```
#include <limits>

//...
std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max() );
```

It seems that your program contains a typo because this statement

```
    if (temporaryname == temporaryname);
```

does not make a sense.

Comment: You should address `if (temporaryname == temporaryname);`

Comment: It's a compile error?  Is that because there's no statement before the semicolon?  The OP seems to suggest that this code actually executes (albeit incorrectly).

Comment: @Robert Harvey Oh, I am not attentive.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow The member function cin.ignore() is the solution to the problem. I recognized that the statement if(temporaryname == temporaryname) is wrong given that it will always be true.

Comment: You should add the two reasons why `if (temporaryname == temporaryname);` doesn't make sense.